# Need to show and hide a div by clicking the same button in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new at query and this is probably really simple : ) Right now it's setup to show a popup div when you click on the details button, which works fine. Now I'm trying to figure out how I can hide that popup div if the user clicks again on that same details button. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".details").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('h1').next('.popup').fadeIn(1000);              
        });     
});       
</script>


                <h1>We look good together<span class="details">Details</span></h1>

            <div class="popup">
                <ul>
                    <li>852</li><!--Square Foot goes here-->
                    <li>2</li><!--Bedrooms goes here-->
                    <li>1</li><!--Bathrooms goes here-->
                    <li>$134,900</li><!--Price goes here-->                 
                </ul>               
            </div>
```

Comment: 1. Accept some of the answers people have provided you. 2. You want the the 'toggle()' function: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fadeToggle()` instead of just `fadeIn()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".details").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('h3').next('.popup').fadeToggle(1000);              
  });     
});
```

```css
.details { display: block; cursor: pointer; font-weight: 600 }
.popup { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>We look good together<span class="details">Details</span></h3>

<div class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li>852</li><!--Square Foot goes here-->
    <li>2</li><!--Bedrooms goes here-->
    <li>1</li><!--Bathrooms goes here-->
    <li>$134,900</li><!--Price goes here-->                 
  </ul>               
</div>
```

jQuery [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thank you : ) And yes I'll click to accept the answer, I wasn't aware I had to do that until yesterday : )